# Play 2.0 not updated

Tags: playframework-2.0, anorm

I'm having a problem with Play 2.0 versions. I need to use anorm's new getAliased method but it's not found:

> > value getAliased is not a member of anorm.MetaData

Meanwhile, it was added in this commit: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/370

My plugins.sbt says the following:

> > addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.0.4")

Why my code is not compiled if the corresponding library code was pushed to master Play 2.0 4 months ago?

My code, just for reference:

> > MetaData(null).getAliased("")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are making a mistake: the pull request that you mention has been pushed to the `master` branch, but not in the `2.0.x` branch.

You can see in the 2.0.4 version of the `SqlParser.scala` file that the `getAliased()` method does not exist : https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.0.4/framework/src/anorm/src/main/scala/SqlParser.scala

Comment: Ok, haven't dug into playframework branches, but somehow thought a change from 4 months ago will be available in 2.0.x release.

Comment: Anyway, in my situation, what should I do? I do need this stuff and it's not released yet. Is there any elegant GitHub-style way (not just local copy-paste) to get this fix to my application?

Comment: I do have a workaround, but it takes 1.4ms instead of 1.2ms of initial aliased query. Don't really want to go with that for a long period of time.